# Kubernetes pods not able to update repositories of debian based

Tags: docker, kubernetes, debian, containerd

Kubernetes pods are not able to update repositories of Debian based.

I have set up the k8s cluster below steps.

Using Kubernetes official links

1. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/
2. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/
3. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/configure-cgroup-driver/

```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install docker.io
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo swapoff -a
   sudo sed -i '/ swap / s/^\(.*\)$/#\1/g' /etc/fstab

   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl
   sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
   echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
   sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
   cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
EOF

   sudo systemctl enable docker
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl restart docker
   
   ## Just in the master node
   sudo kubeadm init  --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
   
   sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
   sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
   kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml
```

```
# Deployed below nginx specs
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80 
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
   app: nginx
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      name: nginx-http
```

```
kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml

kubectl exec -it nginx-56bcb5bb6c-ts7l2  -- bash

After running update from inside pod, throws below errors.
root@nginx-56bcb5bb6c-ts7l2:/# apt update


Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

root@nginx-56bcb5bb6c-ts7l2:/#
```

```
Below is the version of the Kubernetes cluster.

osboxes@k-master:~$ kubectl version
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24", GitVersion:"v1.24.2", GitCommit:"f66044f4361b9f1f96f0053dd46cb7dce5e990a8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-06-15T14:22:29Z", GoVersion:"go1.18.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24", GitVersion:"v1.24.2", GitCommit:"f66044f4361b9f1f96f0053dd46cb7dce5e990a8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-06-15T14:15:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.18.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

osboxes@k-master:~$ kubectl version --short
Flag --short has been deprecated, and will be removed in the future. The --short output will become the default.
Client Version: v1.24.2
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: v1.24.2
```

Why these errors are coming from inside the pod, while an apt update from the host node runs fine?

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a programming question, but maybe more of a question about your cluster's network configuration?  You probably shouldn't run APT commands in a `kubectl exec` shell: in a typical environment where you have multiple replicas of a Deployment this will only affect one of the Pods, and if the cluster deletes and recreates a Pod (maybe its Node went offline) your manual changes will get lost.

Comment: I understand that I shouldn't use them ideally, but for quick diagnosis and troubleshooting, we sometimes need to use certain tools like telnet, nslookup ..etc to check connectivity between services. Anyways my concern is it's throwing those errors in bare-metal clusters While commands work perfectly in cloud-based k8s clusters. What am I doing wrong or missing while setting up k8s cluster on bare metal?

Comment: "Setting up a k8s cluster on bare metal" is not a programming question; the [help/on-topic] describes what's on topic for Stack Overflow.  Consider asking this on another site like [sf] or [devops.se].

Answer (score 1):

Seems issue is with network `does the network require authentication`.

Please check it using another network as I am able to run `apt update` command from with in the container.

```
$ kubectl run mginx --rm -i --tty --restart=Never --image=nginx -- /bin/sh
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.

#
#
#
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
# apt update
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [44.1 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [39.4 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages [154 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages [8182 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages [2592 B]
Fetched 8539 kB in 1s (7158 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
#
```

Comment: Getting the same error, with this as well.  ```kubectl run mginx --rm -i --tty --restart=Never --image=nginx -- /bin/sh```
```If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.       E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)```

Comment: I have setup the cluster in VirtualBox VMs.

Comment: Raised this issue on the slack Kubernetes channel, they feel it is k8s coredns issue. Here's the thread https://app.slack.com/client/T09NY5SBT/C09NXKJKA/thread/C09NXKJKA-1655711689.285079 . But still not resolved. will try to see what else can be done.

Comment: Please refer to below link, as this may resolve your problem. In errors, we can see registry not signed errors are coming.

https://cloudcone.com/docs/article/how-to-fix-the-repository-is-not-signed-error-on-ubuntu-20-04/